# Typeclass constraint inside typeclass instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Hello while doing examples from Real World Haskell book i have encountered this example  and i can not understand what it does mean and how it does work:
`instance Num a=>Num (SymbolicManip a)` 

In this case i should translate to somehting like : "For Num instance of type `SymbolicManip` there is a constraint  regarding its field of type `a`,which is : `a` being an instance of Num  itself"?
Can someone please tell me if i interpreted it right or explain?
Why wouldn't `instance Num (SymbolicManip a)` be enough?

```
-- The "operators" that we're going to support
data Op = Plus | Minus | Mul | Div | Pow
        deriving (Eq, Show)

{- The core symbolic manipulation type -}
data SymbolicManip a = 
          Number a           -- Simple number, such as 5
        | Arith Op (SymbolicManip a) (SymbolicManip a)
          deriving (Eq, Show)

{- SymbolicManip will be an instance of Num.  Define how the Num
operations are handled over a SymbolicManip.  This will implement things
like (+) for SymbolicManip. -}
instance Num a => Num (SymbolicManip a) where
    a + b = Arith Plus a b
    a - b = Arith Minus a b
    a * b = Arith Mul a b
    negate a = Arith Mul (Number (-1)) a
    abs a = error "abs is unimplemented"
    signum _ = error "signum is unimplemented"
    fromInteger i = Number (fromInteger i)
```

**P.S** All code is from the book (**chapter** 13 - **subchapter**-Extended Example-Numeric Types)

Comment: Try compiling the code without the Num constraint and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to see that a `SymbolicManip a` cannot be an instance of `Num` without `a` also being an instance of `Num` So, just like when we add constraints to functions, we can add a constraint to a typeclass:

```
 instance Num a => Num (SymbolicManip a) where
 --       ^^^^^^^^ "As long as `a` is an instance of `Num`..."
 --                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ "...so is `SymbolicManip a`"
```

We **must** include the `Num a =>` constraint, because in the implementation, we use `fromInteger` to produce members of the type `a`. This is **unavoidable**, just like adding a `Num` constraint to the function `example a b = 2*a + b`, i.e. `example :: Num a => a -> a -> a`.

Here's a simpler example. Consider this type:

```
newtype Identity a = Identity a
```

Note that an `Identity a` could be an instance of `Num`, so long as `a` is a `Num` too, so, we add a constraint:

```
instance Num a => Num (Identity a) where
-- (...)
```

Comment: The instance definition doesn't use (+) and (-) on values of type "a". However it does use fromInteger.

Comment: "We **must** include the `Num a =>` constraint" is probably overselling things a bit. Just like the other arithmetic operations are explicitly represented, one could change `SymbolicManip` so that `fromInteger` is explicitly represented -- e.g. by replacing the `Number a` constructor by `Number Integer`. (One could then remove the type parameter entirely, or allow an embedding by adding a `Literal a` constructor or similar.) (1/2)

Comment: Of course, you still would eventually probably want `eval :: Num a => SymbolicManip a -> a`, and here the `Num` instance is much more clearly needed, not just for `fromInteger` but also for the other arithmetic operations. (2/2)

Answer (score 3):

It means that if `a` is an instance of `Num` then `SybolicManip a` is also an instance of `Num`.

So if you have:

```
x :: SymbolicManip Integer
y :: SymbolicManip Integer
```

Then you can write `x+y` without needing to define what that means. But if instead you tried to add two values of `SymbolicManip String` you would get a type error, because `String` is not an instance of `Num`.

If you look at the instance you will see that `negate` and `fromInteger` both use features of `Num`. Hence if you took the constraint out then the compiler would give errors about not being able to deduce that `a` is an instance of `Num`.